# Google social login issue while getting basic profile data

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, google-oauth, gmail-api, react-google-login

currently i am using react and spring boot as google social login.
on react side i am using react-oauth/google and i am getting access token from google side.
but when i call below api from java side 
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token= 
where access_token is the token which i received on react side from google
[image]

but in response i am getting unauthorized error

also note that on google consent screen i have provided all permission

can someone please help me to solve this issue, because also i need to start working on gmail api.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add you email in the allowed list? Since it is in testing, you need to provide an email list of people who can use google login

Comment: Add  your Spring Security conf. My bet is that you are sending a request with a Bearer authorization header **to** an OAuth2 client. Requests to clients are authorized with session, not tokens (only requests **from** OAuth2 clients to OAuth2 resource servers are authorized with access tokens)